# Explain the parameters in default.json of onlyoffice server

Tags: windows, server, onlyoffice

I deployed integration edition of document server on windows machine. I want to make many changes on document server as per my suitability. So I wanted to know the meaning of each and every parameter in default.json to achieve my goal. Is there any proper documentation for default.json so that I could thoroughly know the meaning of each parameter and accordingly use those parameter.

Comment: Its not a question for stack. Go to OO forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such doc. You can try to figure it out by looking at changes for https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/server/blame/master/Common/config/default.json

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately today we do not have complete documentation for default.json. We already have plans for full refactoring of Document Server configuration 
and writing detailed documentation for default.json. We understand the importance of it but any time frames for it could not be specified.
Thank you for the interest in our product.